# Passing return values from one \newcommand to another \newcommand?

Tags: macros

I would like to know how to pass out the output of one `\newcommand` to the input of another `\newcommand`.  For example:

```
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{$\langle{#1}|$}
\newcommand{\comm}[2]{$ \left[{#1},{#2}\right]={#1}{#2}-{#2}{#1}$}
```

`\comm{\bra{X},\bra{Y}}` should return :

```
$\langle X|\langle Y| - \langle Y|\langle X|$
```

Seems simple enough - except I can not figure out the correct syntax or to find a similar question to work off of.

Thanks for your input.

Brian

Comment: If you do `\newcommand{\comm}[2]{...}` then you can't call this like you seem to do, but like `\comm{\bra{X}}{\bra{Y}}`. Leave out all the `$`, to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a comma-separated list of arguments for your `\comm` you could do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle{#1}|}
\newcommand{\comm}[1]{\tempcomm(#1)}
\def\tempcomm(#1,#2){\left[{#1},{#2}\right]={#1}{#2}-{#2}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
\comm{\bra{X},\bra{Y}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A possible definition would be

```
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle#1\mathclose{|}}
\newcommand{\comm}[2]{[#1,#2]=#1#2-#2#1}
```

Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle#1\mathclose{|}}
\newcommand{\comm}[2]{[#1,#2]=#1#2-#2#1}

\begin{document}

$\bra{X}$

$\comm{X}{Y}$

$\comm{\bra{X}}{\bra{Y}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that when you do

```
\newcommand{\foo}[2]{...#1...#2...}
```

you have to call it as

```
\foo{first}{second}
```

and not as `\foo{first,second}`. You shouldn't be using `$` in the definitions of those commands, which are supposed to be used in a formula.

There are better ways for this, however.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bra}{\langle}{|}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\comm}[2]{[}{]}{#1,#2}
\newcommand{\commx}[2]{#1#2-#2#1}

\begin{document}

$\bra{X}$

$\comm{X}{Y}=\commx{X}{Y}$

$\comm[\big]{\bra{X}}{\bra{Y}}=\commx{\bra{X}}{\bra{Y}}$

\end{document}
```

Note that `\comm` and `\bra` accept an optional argument for changing the delimiters' size; also you can use `\comm*` and `\bra*` for automatic sizing (use with care).

[image]